# How to implement structure of linked list or binary tree in MPI?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, linked-list, mpi, binary-tree

In C we define structure for linked list or binary tree like that:

```
struct list{
  int val;
  list *next;
};
```

OR

```
struct tree_node{
  int val;
  tree_node *left, *right;
};
```

we can easily assign pointer of next memory location in serial programming. My question is how do I handle pointer in MPI where multiple processor has its local memory? How do I keep track it? How to implement linked list/binary tree in MPI? I know about MPI_Graph. But it is not useful in my scenario.

I appreciate your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'll discuss a linked list, but all of this applies to a binary tree just as easily with a little extra work.

Implementing a linked list in the classical sense isn't exactly possible in MPI because, as you said, each process has its own local memory which won't be consistent on other processes. So that essentially limits using something simple like point to point messaging unless you want to do a lot of work that wouldn't really make sense.

However, it is possible to do something using one sided communication, or RMA. In fact, there's some example code [here](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/mpi/mpich2/trunk/test/mpi/rma/linked_list.c). The basic idea of RMA is that each rank exposes a region of memory to the other processes. Then, with the appropriate accessors and synchronization calls, each process can get data from and put data into the other processes memory.

The example uses a dynamic window to allow the application to allocate memory as needed, but it's also possible to statically allocate all your memory up front and point each process to it at the beginning of the application, which might make it a little easier to understand.

Whether or not all of this is efficient or the right thing to do is a different argument. For sufficiently large lists, this can be powerful because you can store more data that you would be able to in a single node's memory. However, for small data structures, the costs of traversing the list become rather high, so it's pretty inefficient to distribute the list and it might be more practical to replicate it on each node.

Comment: Welcome to SO! On this site, the way things work is that whenever you have an answer that you like (whether its on your own question or another), you can upvote it by clicking on the arrow on the left side above the number. If it's your question and you think an answer is correct, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark. This helps future visitors with the same question to quickly find good answers.